# Can't skip ViewController with storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate

I get the notification But my app is not running and i open the app through notification so i can't skip ViewController.
That is my code.

AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"username"] && [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"password"] && [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"companyid"])
        {
            HomeViewController  *hm= [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeView"];
            self.window.rootViewController = hm;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"LoginView");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"username"] && [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"password"] && [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"companyid"])
        {
            HomeViewController  *hm= [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeView"];
            self.window.rootViewController = hm;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"LoginView");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean here **so i can't skip ViewController**..?

Comment: @KumarKl forget this.When my app. is not running and i get notification so i open the app through notification so i can't get else part